# Error when multiple Flows are configured in a Spring Batch Job

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I get the following error when the config.xml is being loaded, when I try to run the job which is having multiple flows. The first flow is identified whereas the second flow was not identified.

***Offending resource: class path resource [spring/batch/jobs/myAppConfig.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: The element [job1Flow2] is unreachable***

Every flow has a series of steps and I have various jobs in which various combinations of the steps are required. So I thought of implementing the steps as flows and then re-using the flows so that my jobs have all the steps it requires.

My config file :

```
<batch:job id="job1" parent="parentJob">
        <batch:flow parent="MyFlow1" id="job1Flow1"/>
        <batch:flow parent="MyFlow2" id="job1Flow2"/>
</batch:job>

<batch:flow id="MyFlow1">
        <batch:step id="step1" next="step2" parent="parentStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="bean1"/>
        </batch:step>

        <batch:step id="step2" parent="parentStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="bean2"/>
        </batch:step>
</batch:flow>

<batch:flow id="MyFlow2">
        <batch:step id="step3" next="step4" parent="parentStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="bean3"/>
        </batch:step>

        <batch:step id="step4" parent="parentStep">
            <batch:tasklet ref="bean4"/>
        </batch:step>
</batch:flow>
```

If I comment the second flow and run the job it runs successfully. Please let me know if there is a way to get my task done through flows or any other way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the reason, my silly mistake in configuration of flows in job. I needed to add next attribute for the flows to figure out what should be done next.

```
<batch:job id="job1" parent="parentJob">
    <batch:flow parent="MyFlow1" id="job1Flow1" next="job1Flow2"/>
    <batch:flow parent="MyFlow2" id="job1Flow2"/>
</batch:job>
```